# SQL group by xml path columns

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Tables:

Table 1(unique values):

```
id | NameDep
15    X
16    Y
```

Table 2:

```
id id_department  id_resource
  1  15             45
  2  15             47
  3  16             99
  ....
```

Table 3(about 400records):

```
id_resource resourceName
45          name1
47          name2
99          name3
```

Table 4(contains multiple columns, but we only need for joining this one):

```
id_shift
185281
185282
185283
185284
```

Table 5(shiftName = table3.resourceName):

```
id_shift shiftName id_department
185281   name1      15
185282   name1      15
185283   name2      15
185284   name2      15
```

My current output is:

```
NameDep    id   resourceName              shifts
X           15  name1        185281,185282,185283,185284
X           15  name2        185281,185282,185283,185284
X           15  name3        185281,185282,185283,185284
X           15  name4        185281,185282,185283,185284
X           15  name5        185281,185282,185283,185284
...etc
```

So basically, in resourceName i have all the data from table3
My goal is to group the shifts with the resourceName.
In my exemple 182581 and 182582 belong to resourceName = name1.
182583 and 182584 to resourceName = name2
So, I would like my output to be like this.

Desired output:

```
NameDep    id   resourceName              shifts
X           15  name1        185281,185282
X           15  name2        185283,185284
...so on
```

I've used a temporary table, because I've read it's the only way to have a join between tables and results in xml path as I need. I can't figure out how to change the join / or use the XML PATH in order to have my desired output.
My current SQL IS:

```
select NameDep as region,d.id,r.resourceName     
    into #deps   from table1 d
             join table2 rd on rd.id_department=d.id
             join table3 r on r.id_resource=rd.id_resource
             where NameDep = 'x';

select  SUBSTRING( ( select (',' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),table5.id_shift)) 
                from table4
                join table5 on table5.id_shift =table4 .id_shift
                join #deps on #deps.id_department=table5.id_department
                and #deps.resourceName=table5.shiftName              
                FOR XML PATH( '' ) ) , 2, 100000) as trip3  into #Planned

select * from (
select * 
from
    #deps,#Planned
) t 
 drop table  #Planned,#deps
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use STUFF without using a subquery. STUFF is usually a good place to start when you're trying to compile a delimited list. Also, you don't need table 4.

In this case, you can use ',' + shift FOR XML PATH('') to create a list of comma-delimited shifts grouped by department and resource:

,185281,185282

And then you can use STUFF to chop off the first character and replace it with an empty string, leaving you with:

185281,185282

```
declare @t1 table (id int, namedep varchar(1))
insert into @t1 values (15, 'X')
insert into @t1 values (16, 'Y')

declare @t2 table (id int, id_department int, id_resource int)
insert into @t2 values (1, 15, 45)
insert into @t2 values (1, 15, 47)
insert into @t2 values (1, 16, 99)

declare @t3 table (id_resource int, resourceName varchar(10))
insert into @t3 values (45, 'name1')
insert into @t3 values (47, 'name2')
insert into @t3 values (99, 'name3')

declare @t5 table (id_shift int, shiftName varchar(10), id_department int)
insert into @t5 values (185281, 'name1', 15)
insert into @t5 values (185282, 'name1', 15)
insert into @t5 values (185283, 'name2', 15)
insert into @t5 values (185284, 'name2', 15)

select t1.namedep, t1.id, t3.resourceName, 
    stuff(
    (select ',' + cast(id_shift as varchar(10))
     from @t5
     where shiftName = t3.resourceName and id_department = t1.id
     for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as shifts
from @t1 t1
inner join @t2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id_department
inner join @t3 t3 on t2.id_resource = t3.id_resource
```

Output:

```
namedep  id  resourceName  shifts
X        15  name1         185281,185282
X        15  name2         185283,185284
```

...etc